# In the run dialog, differentiate between two identically named executables

Tags: windows-7, windows, run-dialog

I have installed two versions of the same program: Visual Studio. Both versions have `devenv.exe` as their executable. If I open the run dialog and type `devenv`, then Visual Studio 2012 opens.

I would like to differentiate the two in the run dialog.

- run > `devenv12` opens Visual Studio 2012
- run > `devenv10` opens Visual Studio 2010.

How can I differentiate between two identically named executable in the run dialog?

Comment: In case you were not aware, when you run an exe by shortname in the run bar, it will execute the instance that comes up first when the %PATH% env variable is evaluated, so the order of directories in your path (from left to right) will determine which one gets run.

Answer (score 1):

Using your favorite text editor, create two `.bat` files in a directory that's on the system path that point to the different executables.

*devenv12.bat*

```
@echo off
C:\path\to\MSVS 2012\devenv.exe
```

*devenv10.bat*

```
@echo off
C:\path\to\MSVS 2010\devenv.exe
```

You should then be able to run VS 2010 or VS 2012 exactly as you've written in your question: `devenv10` should open VS 2010; `devenv12` should open VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to rename the applications as you want and they still should execute normally.
2. Specify the **full path** to the file, e.g. **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"**
3. Though not exactly what you ask for, you could create shortcuts to the files and set a keyboard shortcut for each, e.g. <kbd>Crtl+Alt+0</kbd> and <kbd>Crtl+Alt+2</kbd> for v. 2010 and 2012 respectively.

Comment: #1 is very dangerous, as it's impossible to know what sorts of, e.g., registry keys are constructed assuming the executable is named `devenv.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new environment variable on your machine?
You can do this by going to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System", then click on "Advanced system settings" and go to "Environment Variables...".

Add a new variable named devenv10 with the path pointing to the executable of your VS2010. You can then launch VS2010 by running %devenv10%